# JPA/Hibernate select query returning duplicate records

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a table ,say, Instrument with ID,State, and User_ID as columns.

So I have this JPA query to return all the instrument records with a matching
User_ID.

```
   query = manager.createQuery("SELECT instrument from Instrument instrument
             where instrument.User_ID=:User_ID",Instrument.class);
   query.setParameter("User_ID", User_ID);

   List<Instrument> instruments=  query.getResultList();

   for(Instrument instrument:instruments){
            System.out.println("Instrument ID  "+instrument.getID());
              // using sysout as it is not prod code yet
        }
```

It is returning only the first record repeated as many times as there are matching records.

```
11:13:01,703 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Instrument ID   1
11:13:01,704 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Instrument ID   1
11:13:01,704 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Instrument ID   1
```

I have three records in Db with instrument IDs 1,2, and 3

I enabled show sql query on hibernate and the query runs fine on the Database directly
and returns distinct records.

Hibernate Query:

```
    select instrumentjdo0_.User_ID as member_U1_0_, instrumentjdo0_.ID as ID2_0_, 
instrumentjdo0_.state as state4_0_ from instrument instrumentjdo0_ where instrumentjdo0_.User_ID=?
```

Instrument Entity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;




@Entity
@Table(name = "instrument")
public class Instrument{

    @Id
    @Column(name="User_ID", length=9, unique=true, nullable=false)
    String user_ID;

    @Column(name="ID",nullable=false)
    String ID;


    @Column(name="state",nullable=false)
    String state;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return user_ID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.user_ID = userID;
    }


    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: looks like you have posted wrong Query in your question, check it once again --> User_ID=: "user_ID", <-- why you have double quotes here?

Comment: Can you add the query generated by hibernate to your question.

Comment: I have added the hibernate query too

Comment: ok, query looks good. Now how can you say that the query is returning same record multiple times? How you are iterating the list, can you please add that code also?

Comment: I have added the iteration code

Comment: When you run the produced sql query direct on the DB it returns 1 line?

Comment: Please add source code of Instrument entity.

Comment: no it returns all 3 records correctly

Comment: I think I know the issue is .. @ID should be added to the ID field and not the User_ID field as User_ID is the foreign key ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue was that the wrong column in the Instrument Entity had the `@ID` attribute assigned to it.

I removed it from `User_ID` and Added it to `ID` and it worked fine.

Comment: But that will not result in repeated records while running your query right, so whatever records you have in DB has same values for `User_ID`?

Comment: yes all the records that are associated with the same user have the same User_ID.

Comment: oh ok, then this statement is misleading in your question -- `I enabled show sql query on hibernate and the query runs fine on the Database directly and returns distinct records.`

Comment: surprisingly that did return distinct records. I think hibernate does not directly return the result set and does some kind of processing over the results based on @ID etc.

Comment: Got the same issue but I did not have an alternate column on which to put the @Id thus I created a new column.

Answer (score 10):

I also had faced same issue.
    For contact table i marked only `firstname` column as `@Id`.
    And table had multiple rows with same `firstname` due to which first row record with same `firstname` was getting duplicated in entire result set.
    To resolve  this issue i made `IdClass` with first name and last name as id attribute and imported it as id class in my bean.
    Since `firstname` and `lastname` together form unique combination, it resolved my issue.

`Idclass` as below

```
public class ContactKey implements Serializable{

    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;

    public boolean equals(final Object inObject) {
        if (null != inObject) {
            if (inObject.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
                CqCamAdminKey siteKey = (CqCamAdminKey) inObject;
                return (null != this.getFirstName() && this.getFirstName().equals(siteKey.getFirstName()) && null != this.getLastName() && this.getLastName().equals(siteKey.getLastName()));
            }
        }
        return super.equals(inObject);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        if (this.getFirstName() != null && this.getLastName() != null) {
            return this.getFirstName().hashCode() + this.getLastName().hashCode();
        }
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

bean class as below

```
@IdClass(contactKey.class)
public abstract class CqCamAdminDataBean implements DataModelConstants{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7686374823515894764L;

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    @Column(name = FIRST_NAME)
    protected String firstName;


    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = LAST_NAME)
    protected String lastName;

}
```

Comment: in case of composite key, this helps : https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id

Answer (score 2):

Issue with @Id column, If we check closely, @Id column value is same for all the rows. Hence hibernate/JPA not able to get different records, it just get 1st record with this @Id and return duplicate records of it.

Solution - Use @IdClass with columns which result in unique row instead of duplicate row.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to specify `DISTINCT` in your JPQL query: `"SELECT DISTINCT instrument from Instrument instrument where instrument.User_ID=:User_ID"`. For scalar queries, `DISTINCT` essentially removes underlying duplicates from the result set.